# generate a number sequence, and then sort the sequence

Tags: c

I am supposed to write a program that processes a sequence of 100 positive numbers. The program should have 3 different functions, which could be chosen from a menu.

1. Generate a number sequence with a random generator and print the numbers on the screen. The numbers generated should be in the range 0 ≤ n ≤ 900
2. I have to sort the sequence with bubble sort and then the numbers must be printed and I cannot use built-in sorting functions, such as qsort.
3. Quit program.
   The 1 and 2 must be in own functions.
   Lasly every time the program prints out the number, it should be printed as a table with ten rows and ten columns. Choice two can not be made unless choice one has been chosen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 100
#define N 10
#define INVALID 0
#define VALID 1

void randomNum() {
    //random number gen
    int num[SIZE] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      
       num[i] =  rand() % 901;
    }
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%4d", num[i]);
        if(i % 10 == 9)
            printf("\n");
    }  
}

void sort() {
    //sort of the generated number sequence
    int num[SIZE] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    
     for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++)
            {
              if (num[j] > num[j+1]) 
                {
                temp = num[j];
                num[j]   = num[j+1];
                num[j+1] = temp;
                  }
            }
        }
            
         for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%4d", num[i]);
        if(i % 10 == 9)
            printf("\n");
         }   
}


int main() {
    
    randomNum();
    printf("\n");
    
    sort();
    
    
    
    return 0;    
}
```

I have figured out the solutions for how to generate a sequene and sort it and it works correct when all the code are in main() , however, when I put in in own functions above the main() it does not work. I'm stuck and don't know how to move forward. When i run the program it generates a random sequence but then the sorting function just prints out 100 zeros.

Comment: `void sort()` is sorting the local zero'd array `int num[SIZE] = {0};`.

Comment: If you want to share data between functions, you need to be able to hold it somewhere where it persists.  Create an array in main() to hold the values, pass the array to the functions so they can add, sort, print that shared array.  If you create an array variable in the function, it is local to that function and disappears when you leave that function.  Read up on the "scope" of variables.

Comment: So should it look something like this in int main()?
{
int main() {
    int save[SIZE];
    int save[SIZE] = randomNum();
    printf("\n");
    
    sort();
    
    
    
    return 0;    
}
}
I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at abelenky's answer. But, the TL;DR: Remove `int  num[SIZE] = {0};` from _both_ `sort` and `randomNum` functions. They are function scoped variables, so they are _different_ [and don't "see" each other]. Put a global scope definition `int num[SIZE];` just _before_ `randomNum`. Then, both functions will use the same array.

Comment: For your 3 item menu, [here is an implementation](https://ladvien.com/command-line-menu-c/) of a simple console menu written in C that can be adapted for your purpose.  (Its not perfect, so be prepared to do some debug.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up your code, to try to do mostly the same thing in a very straight forward fashion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 100

void fill_random_array( int array[const], size_t sz )
{
    srand(time(NULL));  
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        array[i] =  rand() % 901;
        printf("%3d%s", array[i], (i+1)%16? " ": "\n" );
    }  
}

void sort( int array[const], size_t sz )
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]) 
            {
                int temp   = array[j];
                array[j]   = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int data[SIZE];
    fill_random_array( data, SIZE );
    printf("\n\nResult:\n");
    sort( data, SIZE );
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%3d%s", data[i], (i+1)%16? " ": "\n" );
    }  

    return 0;    
}
```

## Example Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5536KB
757 872 260 877 827 747 839 279 468 311 361 584 382 364 528  24
848  32 307 479 594  59 172  54 811 530 550 451 618 893  39 474
261 597 450 187 740 686 467 307 393 224 288 775 588 816 195 832
848 502 707 838 859 879 892 769 806 839 616 523 831 656  97 191
352 844 676 488 629 539 796 121 763 183 896 747 395 190  74 639
 89 781 873  47 759 865 212  60 199 828 584 129 880  77 618 628
 20 690 216 650 

Result:
 20  24  32  39  47  54  59  60  74  77  89  97 121 129 172 183
187 190 191 195 199 212 216 224 260 261 279 288 307 307 311 352
361 364 382 393 395 450 451 467 468 474 479 488 502 523 528 530
539 550 584 584 588 594 597 616 618 618 628 629 639 650 656 676
686 690 707 740 747 747 757 759 763 769 775 781 796 806 811 816
827 828 831 832 838 839 839 844 848 848 859 865 872 873 877 879
880 892 893 896
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` does not belong in the `fill_random_array()`, which might get called multiple times(although not in your good demonstrative code).  In `main()` is more common.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 100
#define N 10

void fill_random_array( int array[SIZE],  size_t size )
{
int i= 0;
srand(time(NULL));  
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    array[i] =  rand() % 901;    
} 
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    printf("%4d", array[i]);
    if(i % 10 == 9)
        printf("\n");
}
}

void sort( int array[SIZE], size_t size )
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j+1]) 
        {
            int temp   = array[j];
            array[j]   = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    printf("%4d", array[i]);
    if(i % 10 == 9)
        printf("\n");
     }   
}

void calculations(int array[SIZE], size_t size) {
//max och min

int i = 0;
int max = 0;
int min = 900;
int sum = 0;
double average = 0;
double median = 0;
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

    if(array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];   
    }
    if(array[i] < min) {
        min = array[i];
    }    
}  
//average
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
}
average = sum / SIZE;
//median
median = (array[49] + array[50])/2;
printf("Max: %d  Min: %d  Average: %f  Median: %f\n", max, min, average, median);          
}

void binsearch(int array[SIZE], size_t size) {
//binary search

int i = 0;
int pos = 0; //position
int start = 0; //start position i vector
int end = 99; //end position i vector
int number = 0;
int flag;
int row = 0; //row
int col = 0; //column
printf("Enter number: \n");
scanf("%d", &number);
flag = 0;
while(start <= end) {
    
    pos = (start + end)/2;
    if(array[pos] == number){
        row = (pos / N) + 1;
        col = (pos % N) + 1;
        printf("The number %d was found in position %d and row %d and column     %d\n", number, pos, row, col);
         
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    else if(array[pos] < number)
        start = pos + 1;
    else if(array[pos] > number)
        end = pos - 1;
    
    break;
}
 if(flag == 0)
     printf("Number not found\n");     
}    

int main()
{
int data[SIZE];
fill_random_array( data, SIZE );
printf("\n");
sort( data, SIZE );
printf("\n");
calculations( data, SIZE);
printf("\n");
binsearch(data, SIZE);

return 0;    
}
```

This is what my code looks like now. The program works okay now I think but when I run it, it generates a random number sequence, and sort it and then print out max min, average value and median. But when I enter a number for the binarysearch it says: number not found even though the number is in the sorted sequence, how come it does that? And how do I fix it?

Comment: This is not an answer it's a separate question

Comment: I suggest that this _answer_ (which is not an answer at all) be removed by author, and  posted as a new question, possibly linking this post as a reference.